# Samsung Galaxy wont return (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Tags: android, bitmap

```
    String strAvatarPrompt = "Take your picture to store as your avatar!";
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    pictureIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo );
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, strAvatarPrompt), TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_AVATAR_CAMERA_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            } 
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap cameraPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");           

                if (cameraPic != null) {
                    try {
                        saveAvatar(cameraPic);
                    }
```

I have code for users of my app to take pictures. It works fine on the HTC desire. However on the Samsung Galaxy it crashes at the point
  Bitmap cameraPic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

I dont know why it is not working?

Stack-

```
03-31 16:35:15.593: VERBOSE/WindowManager(2497): Delivering toWindow{47fe4340 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.CropImage paused=false}
03-31 16:35:15.761: VERBOSE/WindowManager(2497): Delivering toWindow{47fe4340 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.CropImage paused=false}
03-31 16:35:15.761: VERBOSE/CropImage(6885): Crop = no, Return = specified uri
03-31 16:35:15.773: VERBOSE/CropImage(6885): onPause
03-31 16:35:15.780: ERROR/WindowManager(2497): Overwriting rotation value from 1
03-31 16:35:15.780: VERBOSE/WindowManager(2497): Rotation changed to 1 from 0 (forceApp=0, req=0)
03-31 16:35:15.784: INFO/WindowManager(2497): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
03-31 16:35:15.800: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(2497): Surface Flinger::setOrientation  mIsRotationPossible = 0, nBackupOrientationValue = 1  
03-31 16:35:15.804: INFO/TvOut-Observer(2497): setTvoutOrientation rotation =  1
03-31 16:35:15.804: ERROR/TvOut-Observer(2497): SetOrientation
03-31 16:35:15.804: INFO/ActivityManager(2497): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=234/10 loc=en_GB touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=2 layout=35 uiMode=17 seq=96 FlipFont=0}
03-31 16:35:15.808: DEBUG/PhoneApp(2588): updateProximitySensorMode: state = IDLE
03-31 16:35:15.855: DEBUG/OPPBaseService(7980): [main/1] onConfigurationChanged()
03-31 16:35:15.870: VERBOSE/Camera(5292): --onActivityResult--requestCode: 2001
03-31 16:35:15.870: VERBOSE/Camera(5292): --onActivityResult--resultCode: -1
03-31 16:35:15.870: VERBOSE/Camera(5292): --onActivityResult--data: Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }
03-31 16:35:15.882: WARN/ActivityManager(2497): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{481527f8 com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera}
03-31 16:35:16.038: VERBOSE/CropImage(6885): onDestroy
```

Comment: check to make sure `data` isn't `null` before accessing it.

Comment: @willytate data should not be null as i have just taken the image. I think it is returning null thats the issue

Comment: This response can help people having problems with Galaxy S : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703299/make-picture-intent-failed-on-samsung-galaxy-i9000/6733800#6733800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devices don't return the DATA extra; others only return a very small thumbnail in the extra. You're best off  reading the file from the SD card location in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (which you're already requesting in your original intent) in the callback if it's available, falling back to the data extra only if you can't read the `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286514/intent-image-capture-data-null).