# Intent Image Capture data==null

Tags: android, image, android-intent, capture

I have this code, and it works perfectly in an Ericsson XPERIA, but when I test the app in a SAMSUNG ACE, appears the error :

> data=null

```
String  file=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/picture.jpg";

    Intent i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(archivo));           
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(i,CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

OnActivity Result

```
if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
                    bmp=(Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    image.setVisibility(0);
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and specify a file you usually don't get any image data via the result intent as an extra. The camera app is instead supposed to write the data to the file you specified.

If you include that extra you should read the output from your file instead once you receive `RESULT_OK`. Or you can remove `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to make data in the result intent reliable on all devices. Note that this returns a low-resolution picture since the intent system is not build to deliver huge amounts of data.

Comment: what shall i use then insted of EXTRA_OUTPUT ??

Comment: "you usually don't get any image data via the result " it that in the docs? I just wasted 3 hours trying to figure that out.