# Getting Image from Camera Folder Programatically

Tags: java, android, gallery, android-camera

Folks.

I'm facing a strange issue here. I have an application that you can select an image from Gallery or Camera in a button click. All went well except whenever i select any picture from my camera folder the application just crashed. Hereunder my code

```
case R.id.camera:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);

        builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] { "Gallery", "Camera" },
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                        case 0:

                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");

                            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                    "Choose a Picture");
                            startActivityForResult(chooser,
                                    ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY);

                            break;

                        case 1:

                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            String mImageCaptureUri = null;
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                    mImageCaptureUri);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                                    ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                            break;

                        }
                    }
                });

        builder.show();

        break;
```

Activity for result :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTION_REQUEST_GALLERY:


            Uri selectedImageUri;

            selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();

            cap.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);



            break;

        case ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA:

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            cap.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    finalFile.getAbsolutePath(), 4000).show();

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat with details of the error.

Comment: Unfortunately i use my phone to test it as the emulator doesn't have any picture to choose from.

Comment: It only crashes with the Camera Folder photos, I've my Facebook albums in my gallery and it works fine.

Comment: It could be a case of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502295/samsung-galaxy-wont-return-bitmap-data-getextras-getdata  Can you not connect your phone to your PC to see the logcat? Failing that, Google Play has various Log Collector apps to get the logcat, although those don't work since Android 4.1.

Comment: Now i managed to get the full path of the picture in a Toast before assigning it to the imageview. All photos i select in the gallery are getting the image path for example "storage/sdcard/DCIM/....jpg" but the error is occurring in assigning picture to the imageview. Can anyone show me how to set an imageviwe from the picture path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say without logcat, but most probable reason is large image size, photos taken with camera are to big to show without scaling, this is the reason that some images you tried works while camera images don't. Try to google: scaling larg bitmaps google developers and you will find official post

Comment: Thank you , I found that was the problem. I reduced the selected image from camera folder before i can view it and it works!! Thanks.