# android Camera picture not being displayed

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

the following is my camera code

```
 public void takepic(View view) {
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String schname = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String[] tokens = schname.split(" ");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = tokens[0] + "-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    detail.setText(imageFileName); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String name = imageFileName;
    File file = new File(path, name );
    ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE); 
    new SingleMediaScanner(this, file);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
     if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
         Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
         mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);            
     }}}
```

when invoked it runs the camera app takes a photo and stores it in the Pictures folder with a pre defined filename

problem is it should then display the image in an imageview call mImageView but it doesnt

mImageView already has a bitmap in it. it should change to the new image but instead stays as it s

ouputFileURI reports the correct path and filename but I cant get it to work

Any ideas?

Mark

Comment: Have you verified that `onActivityResult()` is executed? Also have you checked the return value of `data.getExtras().get("data")`? Are you certain this returns a `Bitmap`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Samsung Galaxy wont return (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502295/samsung-galaxy-wont-return-bitmap-data-getextras-getdata)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly giving the file name where to store the image, you should read the `Bitmap` from that file rather than loading it from the `Intent`. It sounds like `data.getExtras().get("data");` is returning `null`.

Comment: thanks for this sorry new to this any idea how i would do that?

Comment: @user3422687 Did you read the link I gave in the comment to your question?